# How to Integrate passport-google-oauth with Thinkster MEAN Tutorial?

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, passport-google-oauth

I just completed the Thinkster MEAN Stack tutorial, and am looking to adapt it for a project of my own. I'd really like to allow users to log in with Google, so I'm trying to use Passport's Google strategy. I've installed passport-google-oauth with npm and I even have it at a point where I can authenticate properly.

I'm stuck on how to integrate the authenticated's user's JWT back into the rest of the Angular app. In the code below, after clicking "Allow" from Google, I get back to my localhost app and just see the JSON of my JWT on the screen. How do I get that JWT back into my Angular auth service to enter into localStorage? With my other login functions, I'm able to use the .success() callback; with Google, my callback is coming from a different domain. I'm guessing that the key to all of this is to let the Angular app handle the JSON, I just don't know how to trigger that.

Thanks a ton for any help you can provide! Here are my files:

passport.js:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        if (!req.user) {
            User.findOne({ 'google.id': profile.id }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User();

                    newUser.google.id = profile.id;
                    newUser.google.token = token;
                    newUser.google.name = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                    newUser.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) { throw err; }
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            var user = req.user;
            user.google.id = profile.id;
            user.google.token = token;
            user.google.name = profile.displayName;
            user.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;

            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }

    });
}
));
```

index.js (express router):

```
.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }
))
.get('/auth/google/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        if (user) {
            return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
})
```

angularApp.js auth service (how localStrategy logins are handled, for reference):

```
auth.saveToken = function (token) {
        $window.localStorage['outside-in-token'] = token;
    };
auth.login = function (user) {
    return $http.post('/login', user).success(function (data) {
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
};
```

and the index.js router that handles posts to /login:

```
.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Please fill out all fields' });
    }

    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        if (user) {
            return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
})
```

**EDIT**
I think I may have found a solution. I'm having a Google callback send the token as a querystring back into my login page. Then, in the `login` state I have set up, I'm checking on enter if `$location.search().token` is defined; if so, I'm using my `auth` service to save the token into localStorage that way. I can probably improve reliability with some additional steps, but I think this works for right now. Is this still secure? I believe it should be, since users could go into localStorage already as it is, but I want to ensure that they can't spoof it or anything.

new index.js router:

```
.get('/auth/google/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        if (user) {
            res.writeHead(302, {
                'Location': 'http://localhost:3000/#/login?token=' + user.generateJWT()
            });
            res.end();
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
})
```

ui-router $state from angularApp.js:

```
.state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: '/login.html',
            controller: 'AuthCtrl',
            onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', '$location', function ($state, auth, $location) {
                if ($location.search().token) {
                    auth.saveToken($location.search().token);
                }
                if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $state.go('home');
                }
            }]
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but I imagine that you could always just add your own jwt with your own secret to the existing passport strategy. that way you can still use passport for the initial login and then use your own token for further auth. This is something I've been investigating myself to see if I could get it going but I haven't been able to finish my PoC yet.